# Meaning of “look off”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, lyrics

In the line from the song [‘Million reasons’ by Lady Gaga](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Texvyo7f5aulizh3uz2aysot2oa?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics&u=0#), what does *look off* mean?

> Head stuck in a cycle, I **look off** and I stare.

I searched an English dictionary. There’s no specific definition which I can understand. Can you explain with some examples how to use this term?

Answer (score 6):

I found it under *off*:

3. away from a place: to run off; *to look off toward the west.*

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/off

In the lyrics you quoted, "I look off and I stare" means:

> I stare into the distance and I space out.

The way you might look out of a city bus window in a quasi-hypnotic state.